# add an item to an array IF conditional statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, append, array-difference

I have a protected array.

```
class Tric_FullCircle_Model_Product_Adapter extends OnePica_FullCircle_Model_Product_Adapter
{
    /**
     * Global company number
     */
    protected $_globalCompanyNumber = null;

    /**
     * Tax Classes
     */
    protected $_taxClasses = null;

    /**
     * Attributes to update
     *
     * @var array
     */    

    protected $_attributesToUpdate = array( 
        'name', 
        'description', 
        'price', 
        'tax_class_id', 
        'weight', 
        'country_of_manufacture', 
        'specifications', 
        'tric_cn', 
        'tric_style', 
        'tric_color', 
        'tric_div', 
        'tric_div_desc', 
    );
```

I want to add 'special_price' if it matches a particular default store which 1.

I keep throwing syntax errors in my protected variable array. Do i use an `array_diff`? or just append it like this `$arr[] = 'special_price';`

I tried something like this

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() !== Mage::app()->getWebsites()[1]->getDefaultStore()->getStoreId()) {
    $arr[] = 'special_price';
}
```

and this

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() === Mage::app()->getWebsites()[1]->getDefaultStore()->getStoreId()) {
    $_attributesToUpdate = array_diff(fieldNames, array('special_price'));
}
```

Comment: Show what you are doing that throws the error.

Comment: use var_export and update your answer so we can help you

Comment: Inside the same class, you should have no problems, you would just do `$this->_attributesToUpdate[] = 'special_price';`

Comment: What about the IF statement... i know my IF statements are correct ... the problem is what you said above putting it together with my IF statements. not sure how to do that.

Comment: oh.. i see what you're saying... drop that inside the { }

Comment: Still getting the syntax error @Rasclatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access your protected array with `$this->`

**Change**

```
arr[] = 'special_price';
```

**To**

```
$this->arr[] = 'special_price';
```

OR

**Change**

```
_attributesToUpdate = array_diff(fieldNames, array('special_price'));
```

**To**

```
$this->_attributesToUpdate = array_diff(fieldNames, array('special_price'));
```

Comment: only if statement is true... i know both of my IF statements would probably work... i'm just not sure how to insert it into that array... does that make more sense?

Comment: I should just be able to use the bottom line of your answer inside my { } correct?

Comment: Where do i put the IF statement so it doesn't throw a syntax error?

Comment: Tell me the array variable you're updating? or put your adding statement here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120185/discussion-between-thismethod-and-zayn-ali).